# Checking to see if the selected array has anything stored in it? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <math.h> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    string information[10][7];

    //This bit should check if theres anything stored currently.
    cout << "\nWhich Slot would you like to store the informaton in ?(1-10)";
    cin >> i;
    i--;

    //input
    for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
        switch(j+1)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\nFirst Name: ";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\nLast Name: ";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\nAge: ";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "\nEmail: ";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "\nDoor Number: ";
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "\nRoad Name: ";
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "\nPost Code: ";
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }

        cin >> information[i][j];
    }

    // output
    for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {   
        switch(j+1)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\nFirst Name: ";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\nLast Name: ";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\nAge: ";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "\nEmail: ";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "\nDoor Number: ";
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "\nRoad Name: ";
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "\nPost Code: ";
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }       

        cout << information[i][j];
    }
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Basically the question is what would i do to this bit of code to check if the array that the user selects has information stored in it already? How do i check. Also i would like to know how i can search up a users details by typing in their age for example even though ive used string is it possible or would i have to use int.?

Comment: Take a look at all the functions in the string library below. empty() and compare() will be helpful. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Answer (score 1):

Using a bool array may incur some overhead but may be helpful if you are doing deletes too:

```
bool stored[10] = {false};

/* ... */

do {
  cout << "\nWhich Slot would you like to store the informaton in ?(1-10)";
  cin >> i;
  i--;
} while (stored[i]);

stored[i] = true;
```

Of course, you can define a class/structure with 7 members for strings and one boolean for this information.

Comment: what overheads does it incur?

Comment: it is the memory that the boolean array uses

Answer (score 0):

Lets begin with the fact that your code looks like your array is back to fron you have ten fields of 7 charcters long. Even if we swap it around, having 10 characters for a name or Email address is quite short. My last name is 9 letters, and I have seen names longer than that.

And finally for your question. You could use the method suggested by perreal. But I would probably simply do `if (string[i][0] == "") ... stuff to do when it's empty ...;`.

Comment: It's 10 slots with 7 fields in each.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `string::length` function (`information[1].length()`)? If it returns 0, then it has not been initialized.

just do a compare to find for something.

Comment: sometimes `empty != uninitialized`, in terms of application logic.